# Monitoring input port node.js

Tags: node.js, gpio

I am trying to send a payload, when an input changes on a digital input port. I'm confused about the right thing to do it.. I'm using Linux standard gpio, by reading values from /sys/class/gpio..

In node.js I am using the fs.readfile. But I can only read the value manually. How do I trigger it by an event change, so I can send the payload everytime the input pin change from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
watcher = fs.watch('./some/path'); //returns an eventEmitter
watcher.addListener('change', (event, filename) => {

        if (event === 'change') {
            fs.readFile('./some/path/', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if(data) {

                    //Do something
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this npm package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpio

It uses node's EventEmitter to tell you when something has changed. Here is a code snippet of getting the event when something has changed -> https://snipp.ly/bVk3GCBy

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem. I used the fs.watch and added a listener. Everytime the file changes, I used a callback function to do whatever I wanted to do.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and post a snippet of the code you used to solve it just in case someone else runs into this problem